# Hypervisor to embed in my product

Tags: linux, virtualization, embedded-systems

I'm looking for hypervisor recommendations for use in a product that has to run a mixed bag of VMs.

The actual product uses a touch screen PC, and runs on Linux. The user only ever sees our application.

We need to integrate some Windows components for data processing, and the easiest (for our users) way to do this is to bury a Windows VM in our product.

**Need:**

- Must support Linux VMs (CentOS 6 presently, hopefully 7 in the future)
- Must support Windows VMs (Win 10)
- Must be able to create private networks for the VMs.
- Must allow VMs to access USB hardware (serial ports, USB drives, card readers)
- Must allow a VM to control the local display

**Want:**

- Ability to manage the VMs locally when debugging systems in the field. (command line access of some sort).
- Bare metal operation - I want to minimize the footprint of the Hypervisor itself on the target systems. If I can't run bare-metal, I don't want to run an MS OS except inside the captive VM.
- Straightforward way to completely swap out a VM from a USB stick image or something.

**Would be nice:**

- Open source/free solution, preferably with available commercial support.

**Things I'm aware of:**

- KVM
- VMWare ESXi - This is what Toshiba uses on the computer running the voice mail for our phone system.
- XenProject & XenServer - What's the differences between these two?
- QEMU
- Oracle VM Server - is that embeddable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up with KVM because the specs changed and I'm no longer running the Hypervisor bare metal, so CentOS 7 became the target OS, and KVM was the easiest thing to use in my environment.

Comment: You can accept your own answer, which will help others who read this question in the future